# Golang redirecting to HTTPS in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, go, https

I'm having problems redirecting HTTP-traffic into HTTPS in my EC2 instance on a Golang-service. The connection works fine when going straight to https://sub.domain.com, but the redirect from HTTP doesn't seem to be working.

There is no load balancer and it's using only the net/http package as the web server.

I'm also using iptables that should be redirecting HTTP/HTTPS requests to ports 8080/8081 respectively.

Just to narrow down the possibilities, the security group applied to the instance has connections to ports 80 and 443 allowed from any IPv4 or IPv6 address.

Here is the server-code that serves HTTPS and is supposed to redirect HTTP requests;

```
    // LetsEncrypt setup
    certManager := autocert.Manager{
            Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
            HostPolicy: autocert.HostWhitelist("sub.domain.com"), // your domain here
            Cache:      autocert.DirCache("certs"),          // folder for storing certificates
    }
    server := &http.Server{
            Addr:      ":8081",
            Handler:   context.ClearHandler(http.DefaultServeMux),
            TLSConfig: &tls.Config{GetCertificate: certManager.GetCertificate},
    }
    // open https server
    err = server.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("ListenAndServe: %s\n", err)
    }
    // redirect everything to https
    go http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            reqhost := strings.Split(r.Host, ":")[0]
            http.Redirect(w, r, "https://" + reqhost + r.URL.Path, http.StatusMovedPermanently)
    }))
```

Here are my PREROUTING rules from iptables, other chains are empty;

```
    Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    7   420 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https redir ports 8081
   45  2508 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 8080
```

Both redirects are getting packets on requests, but the 8080 just wont redirect the connection to the HTTPS side.

Comment: are you using any web server(nginx or apache) for your application

Comment: No webserver, just the net/http package.

Comment: *"8080 just wont redirect the connection"*  So, if it doesn't do the HTTP redirect, then what **does** it do?  Handle the request as normal?  Time out?  Connection refused?

Comment: Using curl for a normal HTTP-connection says that the connection is refused, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `port` in the redirect

> http.Redirect(w, r, "https://" + reqhost + r.URL.Path + ":" + port,
>   http.StatusMovedPermanently)

You need to add port in there.
Also you can use postman in the request to see what is the location URL that is sent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Tried this fix, still even Postman can't get any response. Shouldn't the port be inserted after the host, not the entire path anyhow?

Comment: Read the edited question.  The setup is using iptables to map 80 > 8080 and 443 > 8081.  There's no need to specify any ports in the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I checked what was listening on my ports with

```
netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

..and there was apache listening on port 80. Either shutting it down or removing it works just fine.